# Synchronize separate ScrollViewer and ScrollBar with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have a Grid which consists of a ScrollViewer and a ScrollBar which are separated (i.e. the ScrollBar is not bound to the ScrollViewer)

I want both to be synchronized, for instance if the ScrollViewer's VerticalOffset property changes, I want the value of the ScrollBar to change, and vice-versa. I really insist that both should be separated (because in my real project the ScrollViewer is located on a different View)

```
<Grid Height="200" Width="400">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Background="Gray" />
    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Width="30" />
</Grid>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you can do this merely by binding a couple of properties.

I think the way to do this is to create two completely separate ScrollViewers and link them together.   The one on the left has its scroll bar visibility properties set to hide its scroll bars so all you see is the view.  The one on the right just shows the ScrollBar part.  (It's possible this might require you defining a custom control template to achieve that effect but it can be done).

Then link them together in code-behind.  Use the ScrollChanged event.  For example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/43474/wpf-how-to-make-two-panels-share-the-same-vertical.html